CameraException(INVALID_PATH, The platform "TargetPlatform.android" did not return a path while reporting success
CameraException(INVALID_PATH, The platform "TargetPlatform.android" did not return a path while reporting success.The platform should always return a valid path or report an error.
Only getting this issue some android device
Camera video uploaded successfully
